# How to do a Exact Match On One Field and Partial Match On Another in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a business requirement to have an exact match on the entity_type field and then a partial match on the predicates.name.value field with the results sorted for exact matches first.

Below is what I have for the query for the exact match for both.  How would I change it so that it is a partial match for the predicates.name.value field with the exact matches sorted first?

```
self.search = {
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "entity_type" : entity_type
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "predicates.name.value" : criteria
                    }
                },

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this;

```
self.search = {
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "entity_type" : entity_type
                    }
                },
                {"query": {"wildcard": {"predicates.name.value": {"value": "*criteria*"}}}},

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I found that this works:  

"query" : {
 "bool" : {
  "must" : [
   {
    "match" : {
     "entity_type" : entity_type
    }
   },
   {
    "wildcard": {
     "predicates.name.value.keyword": {
     "value": criteria
     }
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}